# How to detect when a user is running from Visual Studio or when it's a regular running service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, authorization

I am working on a cloud system (using Azure and .NET core) which uses all sorts of files in a file share that services sitting in the cloud can access. This can be any file with a json format.

I want to develop (did not start yet so I have no code to show - this is a design) a sort of an authorization system and i got an issue with it.

I'll first just describe the new "system" - Every json file will have a new section with a list of the services allowed to gain access to that file and if the requesting service is not in that new section, no reading or writing action will be allowed for that service. In order to know the identity of the service, I will get the `Environment.MachineName` and there are a number of existing service's names which will be added to each file manually before the authorization itself will be committed to the code in the cloud.

Now for the issue I have - other developers of the system can run the services locally from Visual Studio and try to work with a file. In which case, the `Environment.MachineName` is his local computer's name, which doesn't have any access to any file. Do you have any thoughts of how I can detect when a user is running the service from his local computer and how in such a system to know he should be authorized to gain access to a file he wants to use?

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe this project, it sounds like each service will check if it has access to that particular file. I absolutely would not do that.

If this is a microservice thing, you can use the API gateway to authorize.

If it is something else, you could make a service in front of your files. Some sort of firewall/router, which authorizes the other services and accesses the files for them to see if they are allowd and then perform reading and writing action son these files. Some secure man in the middle.

I would like to wanr you for this way of working. If I can guess the name of one of your services, then I might be able to forge a request and access the files. Therefore, use some sort of authentication before you authorize anyone. That might be done by a secret key/password, some sort of signing mechanism, IP whitelisting, etc. And most preferably a combination of two or more of the just mentioned methods.

Comment: There is indeed a service which is responsible for the reading and writing of the files which is a gRPC service with an SDK which provides a general API for that service. The service is the one who is checking if the requesting service is authorized. The issue is like I said that this service is checking the file for a section in its json if that service is there and I don't know how to get being authorized when the machine name is different when the user is running them locally from the IDE

Comment: @YonatanNir Is it really required to use the machine's name?

Comment: the services are running in a docker, each in its own pod. I don't know how else I can identify the service without using the machine name which is the pod's name. I can't rely on a parameter which the user sends me

Comment: @YonatanNir What if you gave each service a unique name or ID or something? They don't have to be GUIDs or other unique identifiers over different systems, but some unique value within your system / group of services. And then send that unique name with each request. That way, you don't need to send user data.

Comment: that name you suggested is actually the pod's name I mentioned. And i can't rely on a request that the users of the service send because there can also be outside users and I don't want them to send that information. That's why it has to be a way in which I detect the name of the service myself and not by a given input

Comment: Okay, but that name changes per machine/container. I meant a constant value, holding a name for that service, which gets sent by the service itself, not by the external user. So the service which tries to access the authorization service sends its name, which is set in some constant.
That way, you can just debug using VS, without having to think about the name of the machine. Because, the name of the service being debugged is the same as the service that actually runs in production.
So summarized: exactly what you're doing now, but not with a machine-specific value. :)

Comment: How will this constant be passed on exactly? Remember that when I described the file service, I have also said there was an SDK to give an API for the service? So this SDK is open for external users also... If I understood you correctly, it sounds like it means a user using that SDK will have to send that constant and I want to avoid it because he can be an external user

Comment: So that SDK accesses the file service directly? If so, then you check the machine's name of the user, which is data the user sends too.

If that SDK accesses different services and these different services access the file service, then you set the constant in these services the user accesses and send it with each request the service sends out to the file service.

Comment: It's an SDK that access the file service directly and only it. The MachineName is what I'm already using as mentioned in the question, but then the issue of the question occurs.

Comment: Okay, but then you only have to give access for the developer machines?

Small note though: you already take user-generated values there. So I don't see what's the clue in wanting to avoid other user data? Annd keep in mind that a machine's name can be changed quite easily... For example, I register with your service with my machine called DESKTOP-1A2B3C so that name gets access. Then, I change my machine's name as I don't find it descriptive. I now call my machine Desktop-Jordy-1. And what happens? I don't have access to your file service anymore.

Comment: but i can't just give access to random developers to files.. its supposed to be access for services, not users. Also, a user can use a service which doesn't suppose to have access to the file and then bypass the authorization check.